# How to make strings within strings optional in python

Tags: python, regex, datetime, cgi

I am writing to write something where there are two variables that are formatted in datetime format. The way the user may input their date and time may have the letter "Z" at the end of it. For example:

```
"2008-01-01T00:00:01Z"
```

The user may or may not enter in the "Z" at the end so I want to do something that makes either format acceptable. Here's what I have:

```
import datetime
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("2008-01-01T00:00:01Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
c = datetime.datetime.strptime("2008-05-01T23:59:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

def startTime(b):
    try:
       datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    except:
       print "Error: start time is invalid."

def endTime(c):
    try:
       datetime.datetime.strptime(c, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    except:
       print "Error: end time is invalid."
```

Comment: simply make it optional `Z?`

Comment: `rstrip` the user input?

Comment: Those are in RFC 3339 format. I'd just parse them with something like [`python-rfc3339`](https://github.com/tonyg/python-rfc3339).

Answer (score 1):

How about just manually removing the `Z` if it is there?

```
user_in = raw_input("Please enter a date")
if user_in.endswith('Z'): user_in = user_in[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`rstrip` can remove the `Z` for you if it exists, and leave the string alone otherwise:

```
>>> "2008-05-01T23:59:00Z".rstrip("Z")
'2008-05-01T23:59:00'

>>> "2008-05-01T23:59:00".rstrip("Z")
'2008-05-01T23:59:00'
```

So if you have a date `s` in string format,

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s.rstrip("Z"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

will handle both cases.